# Alter sequence using jdbctemplate

Tags: sql, spring, jdbctemplate

I need to execute the below alter command using jdbc template(not sure if alter statement can be used in jdbctemplate).

ALTER SEQUENCE MY_SEQ INCREMENT BY <>;

The number will be passed dynamically.

Please help.

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

This is my function.

`int incremento= 10;`

`String sql="ALTER SEQUENCE esquema.scuencia INCREMENT BY ";`

`String update=sql+incrmento;`

`jdbcTemplate.update(update);`

The user needs to have special privileges to modify the sequence.

Comment: besides of being eventually a valid answer, please translate into English, which is the official language of Stack Overflow, thanks a lot

Comment: Is this chinees? I understand nothing what your saying. Please use English